# Structring jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, scope, structure

I'm writing a jQuery plugin and getting regularly confused by the scope of certain functions (as is tradition when using jS).

A short example should help:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    var methods = {

        init: function ( options ) {
            var settings = $.extend ({
                a: 100,
                b: 200
            }, options);

            return this.each(function(){

                var $this = $(this);
                var return_value = $this.plugintest("method_1", settings);
                $this.plugintest("method_2", settings, return_value);
            });
        },

        method_1 : function ( settings ) {

            var method_1_value_1 = settings.a * 10,
                method_1_value_2 = settings.a * 20;

            return method_1_value_1;
        },

        method_2 : function ( settings, old_return_value ) {

            // WHAT IF I WANT BOTH method_1_value_1 AND method_1_value_2 in here?
        }
    };

    $.fn.plugintest = function (method) {

        if ( methods[method] ) {

            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call ( arguments, 1 ) );

        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {

            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );

        } else {

            $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist in jQuery.robottest' );
        }
    };
}) (jQuery);
```

See method_2. I want to access the values that I created in method_1, however I can only return 1 value - should I create a Global variable of some sort? What is the 'best' way to do this?

Comment: You could return an object from `method_1` with properties for each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are visible in the function where they are declared (i.e. the function where their `var` statement appears) and in any functions that are declared within that function.

Here's an example:

```
(function () {
    var foo;

    // foo is visible here, bar is not
    // declare variables that should be visible to your whole plugin here

    var methods = {
        a: function () {
            var bar;
            // foo and bar are both visible here
        },

        b: function () {
            // foo is visible here, bar is not
        }
    };
}());

// neither foo nor bar are visible here
```

You should never use global variables (i.e. variables that aren't declared with the `var` statement inside a function). These are visible to all other code in your document. However, as long as you enclose everything in a `function` and always use `var` you're safe.

Comment: And this is an okay thing to do? I tried doing this and was told it was bad practise.

Comment: Okay great - thanks. Was expecting a complicated workaround but this is very easy!

Comment: It's not the only way to go (based on the code in question anyway). You could return an object from `method_1` e.g. `return { value1: method_1_value_1, value2: method_2_value_2 };`. It's down to preference really. If `method_1_value_2` is only used inside `method1` and `method2` there's no point making it available in a wider scope.

Comment: By what, or who, were you told it was bad practice?

Comment: I suspect you've been told *global* variables are bad practice. I've update the answer to explain the difference.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: True, but since the question mentions scope, I thought it was better to explain how that works. You're right that returning an object is sometimes a better solution, depends on what you're going for.

Comment: @georgebrock - exactly right - warned away from Global variables but I understand the difference now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best start: **[jQuery Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/)**

Answer (score 0):

Variables defined within a function will be in the function scope. Anything declared previously before the function will be in the parent scope. The parent scope, depending on your variable declaration will be visible by your functions within the parent.

So, if you declare your variables within your parent, and by not declaring them again in your inner functions, will result in access to the both variables from your inner functions.